# Api Platform: Conditionally adding group to serialization context based on requested resource item

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I am using API Platform 2.0 with Symfony 3.1.

I followed the WIP documentation to add groups to serialisation context conditionally. For that I decorated the ContextBuilder.

This works well to set some groups based on currently logged in user.
But now I additionally want to add some groups depending on the requested resource item - so I need that to be available as Object, already fetched from persistence layer.

Something like this:

```
public function createFromRequest(Request $request, bool $normalization, array $extractedAttributes = null) : array {
    /* @var $currentUser User */
    $currentUser = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

    /* @var $requestedProduct Product */
    $requestedProduct = $this->getRequestedItem();

    if ($product->getAuthoringOrganization() === $currentUser->getOrganization() {
        $context['groups'][] = 'api_products_get_item_current_user_is_owner';
    }

    return $context;
}
```

I am afraid i cant get the requested item / collection in ContextBuilder. If so, i would be really happy to get some advice where to build my serialisation groups.

In EventListener i can do that to get what i called "$requestedProduct" here:

```
$subject = $event->getControllerResult())
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Cheers Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is available from the request attributes:

```
$request->attributes->get('data');
```

See https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/2d252cfe1a188cc0d05c70a78d111b7e54c6d650/src/EventListener/ReadListener.php#L61

Comment: Thank you very much, right now i wanted to complete my question and saw you already added the comment from pull request discussion. Thanks a lot for your help!